# Proof with Fundamental Theorem of Calculus

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

If $f'(t)\leq 10$ for $0 \leq t \leq 5$ and $f(0)=3$: How I can explain with $\int_a^b f'(t)\,dt=f(b)-f(a)$ what the maximum of $f(5)$ is?

Answer (score 2):

Just write that 
$$
f(5) = 3 + \int_0^5f'(x) dx
$$

Now use the inequality:
$$
f\le g \implies \int f(x)dx\le \int g(x)dx
$$

Comment: thanks for your answer. But what does $g(x)$ stands for? It's only function f I should use.

Comment: $g$ is any function such as $f\le g$. Here $g(x) = 10$

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:*
$
f(5)=f(0)+\int_0^5 f'(t)\,dt
$

Answer (score 1):

$\int_0^5 f'(t)\,dt ≤ \int_0^5 10 \,dt = 10\int_0^5 dt = 10(5-0)=50$

$\int_0^5 f'(t)\,dt =f(5)-f(0)$

$f(5)=f(0)+\int_0^5 f'(t)\,dt$

$f(5)≤f(0)+50$

so the max of $f(5)=53$

cheers